# Spring Data MongoDB and @ID as integer instead of BigInteger

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm new with MongoDB and NoSQL.

I created this 2 convertes for Spring Data MongoDB:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class IntegerToObjectIdConverter implements Converter<Integer, ObjectId> {

    @Override
    public ObjectId convert(Integer source) {
        return source == null ? null : new ObjectId(BigInteger.valueOf(source).toString());
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class ObjectIdToIntegerConverter implements Converter<ObjectId, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convert(ObjectId source) {
        return source == null ? null : new BigInteger(source.toString(), 16).intValue();
    }
}
```

I plugged they in the MongoDB converters, and they worked (in very small scenes).

Is it correct? Can I convert between Integer <> BigInteger without lose information?

Comment: I have a feeling that your converters are not actually running, as BigInteger's toString() method does not produce String instances that are compatible with the ObjectId constructor.

Perhaps if you write what you're trying to accomplish instead of providing a solution to an unstated problem, someone will be able to help you.